# Align problem - z-index issue

Tags: html, css, z-index, alignment

Right, I have a header and a small div **.sideShadow**, I need **.shideShadow** div to be behind a **#sideTopHeader** div, right now it is on the top of it, you can see it here (to your right)

http://inelmo.com

**CSS I use now**

```
#sideTopHeader {
background: #333333;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 -30px 0 0;

-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
-khtml-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
}

.sideShadow {
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #1f1f1f;
border-width: 15px;
border-style: solid;
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 395px;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the markup: don't use a `z-index` on `#sideTopHeader` (BTW: why is this an ID? Is there really only one element inside the sidebar?) and set the `z-index` to `-1` for `.sideShadow`.

But I really suggest, you'd better clean up your markup. You don't really need three nested DIV's for styling a single content-element. For example instead of having a nested `div.sideShadow`, you may use a pseduo-element for CSS-effects, like `#sideTopHeader:after`.

Comment: Just be aware the pseudo-selector won't work in IE7 and is wonky in IE8.

Comment: @kinakuta That's why I preferably link to the sitepoint.com-reference:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after#compatibilitysection ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@llya; put your `.slidershow` div outside of yours `#sideTopHeader` div instead of inside like this

HTML:

```
<div id="sideTopHeader"></div>
<div class="sideShadow"></div>
```

& `position relative` to it's parent . May be that's work for you